# JavaScript - Redirect to a page after radio button submit

Tags: javascript, html

I have two radio Buttons in my Page ( Client And Owner ) And i want the user to be redirected to the Client.html page if he chekcs the Client button and redirected to Owner.html if he chekcs the Owner button.
Here is my code :

```js
function jump() {
  var select = document.getElementByName("user");
  for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    var value = selected[i].value;
    if (selected[i].checked) {
      if (value === 'Client') {
        window.location.href = 'Client';
      } else {
        window.location.href = 'Owner';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Registration :</h1>
<script src="jump.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>Are you a Client or an Owner ?</p>
  <input type="radio" name="user" value="Client" checked> Client<br>
  <input type="radio" name="user" value="Owner"> Owner<br>
  <input type="button" onclick="jump()" value="OK">
</form>
```

The other .html Files client and Owner just contain a title.
Thank you..

Comment: `getElementsByName` not `getElementByName`. Also you named your variable `select` and are trying to reference it with `selected`.

Comment: Also, what is `selected` equal to? You define a line above that `select` then reference `selected` everywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `getElementsByName` not `getElementByName`.
Also you named your variable `select` and are trying to reference it with `selected`

```js
function jump() {
  var selected = document.getElementsByName("user");
  for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    var value = selected[i].value;
    if (selected[i].checked) {
      if (value === 'Client') {
        window.location.href = 'Client';
      } else {
        window.location.href = 'Owner';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Registration :</h1>
<script src="jump.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>Are you a Client or an Owner ?</p>
  <input type="radio" name="user" value="Client" checked> Client<br>
  <input type="radio" name="user" value="Owner"> Owner<br>
  <input type="button" onclick="jump()" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: We could improve this by removing the “if value === ‘client’” conditional and just using “window.location.href = value”

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code is checking the wrong things - you should try doing this instead:

```
function hump() {
    var client = document.querySelector("input[value='Client']");
    if (client.checked) {
        window.location.href = "Client.html";
    } else {
        window.location.href = "Owner.html";
    }
}
```